# Bounds for sum of the largest eigenvalues of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are two Hermitian and positive semidefinite matrices. We know from the Weyl's inequality that
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1(\mathbf{A+B})\le\lambda_1(\mathbf{A})+\lambda_1(\mathbf{B}),
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue. I wonder whether there is an upper bound for $\lambda_1(\mathbf{A})+\lambda_1(\mathbf{B})$ related to $\lambda_1(\mathbf{A+B})$? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $\max\{\lambda_1(A),\lambda_1(B)\}\leq \lambda_1(A+B)$, since $A,B$ are positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices. Thus, $\lambda_1(A)+\lambda_1(B)\leq 2\max\{\lambda_1(A),\lambda_1(B)\}\leq 2 \lambda_1(A+B)$.

Edit:
Moreover, this inequality is sharp.

Let $A=\left(\begin {array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&0 \end{array} \right)$ and $B=\left(\begin {array}{cc} 0&0\\ 0&1 \end{array} \right)$. Thus, $A+B=\left(\begin {array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&1 \end{array} \right)$.

Notice that $\lambda_1(A)+\lambda_1(B)=2=2\lambda_1(A+B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, it is possible to derive tighter bounds? Because the Weyl's inequality is applied to Hermitian matrices, now we have positive semidefinite, can we do better?

Comment: @seuhoww  You are welcome. I don' know if there is a tighter bound. I will think about it.

Comment: @seuhoww The inequality is indeed sharp. See my edit.

Comment: Indeed. Is this conclusion only established when the two matrices are full rank?

Comment: @seuhoww These matrices are not necessarily positive definite. The argument above works for every positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices $A,B$. Probably the equality $\lambda_1(A)+\lambda_2(B)=2\lambda_1(A+B)$ only holds for positive semidefinite.